# C# .NET : Showing a simple list with a 32x32 icon column and a 2 line text column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, controls

I'm using .NET 2.0 with standard controls. I want to display a simple list with the following formatting:

[image]
<sub>(source: [telenet.be](http://users.telenet.be/v2/list.jpg))</sub>

- Column1 contains a 32x32px icon
- The second column contains 2 text lines:

  - 1 Bold formatted text line
  - 1 Non bold line
- Rows are separated by a dotted line (3px space, 1px dot, 1px height)

What's the best way to do this ?

.... edit: .....

- We tried this using ListView, but you can't add 2 lines in a column with different formatting ... same with datagridview ...
- ObjectListView would do the trick, but we cannot use this because it has GPL licensing ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use this one: [A Much Easier to Use ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx)

If not you can create your own: [How to: Create an Owner-Drawn List Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229679.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

How about a Listview in Tile mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8z85th0.aspx

For more control you would need to owner draw a listview (or list box)

Comment: Because there are 2 almost identical answers, we voted for the first submitted post ... sorry I cant vote 2 answers, I'll give you +1 though, thanks ..